# GraphViz dirType does not seem have any effect

Tags: graphviz, dot

Simple example:

```
digraph G {
    dirType="back"
    a -> b
}
```

I would expect this to make a graph with an arrow coming from `b` and pointed at `a`. Instead I get a graph with an arrow from `a` pointed at `b`, as if the dirType was not there.

I am using GraphViz 2.28 (2.28.0) for Snow Leopard.

Is there something that I'm missing, or this is a known bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out. It's supposed to be like this:

```
digraph G {
    edge [dir="back"]
    a -> b
}
```